# Adding a UIView as a subview of the openGLView shows a flicker when opening the scene

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, init

When I add a subview to the openGLView in my cocos2d scene init a flicker is shown

```
-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    _overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
    self.overlay.alpha = 0.6f;
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:_overlay];
    ....
}
```

Does anyone know how to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with this change:

```
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                               depthFormat:0
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
```

I used to have:

```
multiSampling:YES
numberOfSamples:4];
```